# How does doubling the de Broglie wavelength affect the kinetic energy of a subatomic particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, particle-physics, wavelength

I'm an AQA A-level student revising for my exam next week and I came across a question that I managed to solve, but a friend of mine used a different method and got the wrong answer. However, my teacher and I can't see the mistake in his workings.

The question I'm working with is:

> A subatomic particle with kinetic energy $E$ has a de Broglie wavelength $\lambda$. What is the kinetic energy of an identical particle with de Broglie wavelength $2\lambda$?

The method I used is:

$$mv = \frac{h}{\lambda} \text{ and }E=\frac{1}{2}mv^2 \implies E= \frac{1}{2}\times (mv)^2 \times\frac{1}{m}= \frac{1}{2}\times(\frac{h}{\lambda})^2\times\frac{1}{m}=\frac{h^2}{2m\lambda^2}.$$

By inspection, you can see that when $\lambda$ is doubled, $E$ is quartered. This is the correct answer according to the revision book I referenced this from.

The method my friend used is similar; the only difference is that, when substituting $h/\lambda$ into the kinetic energy equation, he did it as follows:

$$E=\frac{1}{2}\times mv^2=\frac{1}{2}\times mv \times v=\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{h}{\lambda} \times v=\frac{vh}{2\lambda}$$

Thus, when $\lambda$ is doubled, $E$ is halved. This is incorrect according to the revision book.

I initially thought his method was incorrect due to $v$ perhaps not being constant when $\lambda$ is doubled.  However, the question doesn't specify any change in velocity; in fact, the altered particle is identical except for $\lambda$!

Comment: If it's any consolation this is a very bad question. Does 'identical' mean the same mass (your answer) or the same velocity (your friend's answer).  And if it's a subatomic particle it may well be travelling at relativistic speeds and $KE=mv^2/2=p^2/2m$ is wrong, you need $KE=\sqrt{p^2 c^2+m^2c^4}-mc^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your friend gets the wrong answer because he doesn't take into account the fact that the speed is proportional to $1/\lambda$. You can check this explicitly by the de Broglie equation: $$p=\frac{h}{\lambda} \implies v=\frac{h}{m\lambda}.$$  So when the wavelength is doubled, the speed is halved, i.e. $v'=v/2$.  Using this, it is easy to verify that the two formulas for the kinetic energy are equivalent, and the energy does in fact get quartered, i.e. $E'=E/4$.  Additionally, I would say that the best method to compare two quantities is not by inspection, but rather by taking their **quotient**:

$$\frac{E}{E'}=\frac{\frac{vh}{2\lambda}}{\frac{v'h}{2\lambda'}}=\frac{v\lambda'}{v' \lambda}=4 \implies E'=\frac{E}{4}.$$

Indeed, this is the method by which you are guaranteed to get the correct result:

$$\frac{E}{E'}=\frac{\frac{h^2}{2m\lambda^2}}{\frac{h^2}{2m(\lambda')^2}}=\frac{(\lambda')^2}{\lambda^2}=4 \implies E'=\frac{E}{4}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Of cause, if m is constant and $\lambda$ changes v changes , you used it in your own calculation. Your friends solution is not wrong, but it gives the energy depending on v and  $\lambda$  not on $\lambda$  alone.